# About Power supply for Pi 4b

Tags: power, power-supply

I have bought Pi 4b but now I don't wanna buy separate power adapter for it, I already have 5V,4A power adapter of my smartphone so can I use it for Pi 4b also??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 4B is rated for 3A by the manufacturer. You can always use a charger that can deliver higher current. It is necessary that your charger must not exceed rated voltage, which in this case is 5V. Usually, 5V adaptors give out ~5-5.8V, which the Pi can handle without any issues.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that an RPi can safely handle 5.8V.

Comment: I have checked and verified several of Raspberry Pi power adaptors and all of them deliver somewhere around 5.8V. I have been running several Pi with such adaptors for years now, and I haven't' faced any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can feed it 5V on pins 2 and 4, and return GND on pin 6. 5.25V is best.